# How do you maintain image background transparency when overlaying an image over video?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a site with a looping video for a background that has an image with a transparent background overlayed over the video. I am able to create the video background and overlay an image but when I do so, the transparent parts of the image become filled in with white. This makes my image appear as if it is in a white box when I just want the non-transparent content to be visible. Is there a way to prevent this?

To provide some additional information, the image and video share the same parent div with the image coming before the video. The video is an mp4 file and the image is a png. The image has no CSS applied and the video has the following applied at the moment:

```
video {
    margin-top: 4em;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    filter: saturate(75%);
}
```

Comment: Does your image have a white background...?
Does it happen on every browser?
Can you reproduce the bug in a minimal working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to provide more code to show us the issue. Using your `video` CSS alone, I was not able to reproduce the problem.

In fact, here's a working demo with what you're asking for working just fine:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

video {
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: saturate(75%);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/VRV5rlZ.png">

  <video autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-576p.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried adding your img styling as I had none. Adding position: absolute did the trick. Thanks!